# Как конвертировать DataTable в IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf

С помощью `Binding` вытянуть данные элемента из плитки и вставить в `ItemsControl`, но столкнулся с проблемой, данные из бд загружаю в плитку с помощью `DataView`, но `ItemsControl` треубет `IEnumerable`. Не наше красивого кода для преобразования. Писать колхозный код не хочу

Ошибка: `Cannot convert 'System.Data.DataRowView' from type 'DataRowView' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: ReferenceConverter не может выполнить преобразование из System.Data.DataRowView.`

xaml:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="Header" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Plitka, Path=SelectedItem}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding LogoHome}"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding Home}"/>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="(Away)"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="VS" FontSize="35" FontFamily="Rubik"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding Starttime}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding LogoAway}"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding Away}"/>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="(Home)"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
        
        <ListBox x:Name="Plitka" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Width="300" Height="300" Margin="10,10" CornerRadius="10">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Width="75" Height="75" Source="{Binding LogoHome}"/>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding Home}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="isRunning" Foreground="White" Background="Red" Text="{Binding Status}" FontSize="20"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Image Width="75" Height="75" Source="{Binding LogoAway}"/>
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Rubik" Text="{Binding Away}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" Margin="0,20"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

cs:

```
class Loader
        {
            public static DataView MatchUp { get; set; }
    
            private static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=RADIANCE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NBAShort;Integrated Security=True");
    
            private static SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    
            public static void getDataMatches()
            {
                try
                {
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT Team.TeamName as Home, Team.Logo as LogoHome, Team_Home_Score, t.TeamName as Away, t.Logo as LogoAway, Team_Away_Score, Starttime, Location, Status FROM Matchup INNER JOIN Team on (Team_Home = TeamId) INNER JOIN Team as t on (Team_Away = t.TeamId)", con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                    MatchUp = dt.DefaultView;
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из кода только видна неоднозначная конвертация DataView в Collection<DataView>. Может, инициализировать `public static ICollection<DataView> MatchUp = new List<DataView>();`, и изменить добавление на `MatchUp.Add(dt.DefaultView)`?

Comment: @aepot Указал ошибку и причину

Comment: @Arkee не сработало, сам вопрос был задан не правильно

Comment: `DataView` [реализует](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-Ru/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview) `IList`, вам не нужно ничего преобразовывать, чтобы засунуть это в `ItemsSource`. Если путаетесь с DataTable и прочими прелестями ADO.NET, научитесь использовать ORM, например Entity Framework. И будут вам готовые коллекции, к которым можно прикручивать вьюмодели и биндиться к свойствам класса.

Comment: Кстати, а с чего вы решили, что элемент коллекции `DataView`, то есть `DataRowView` - это коллекция? Откройте [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview). Пытаетесь искать коллекцию внутри коллекции, почему и зачем?

Comment: @aepot да, `DataView` имплементит `IEnumerable', но ошибка почему-то возникает, мне нужно решить эту проблему. На счет EF идея хорошая, но мне для обучения требуется ado

Comment: @aepot мне необходимо решить данную ошибку, но все мои идеи закончились, пробовал вместо `DataView` использовать разные типы данных, которые связанны с коллекциями, но ничего не получается

Comment: @aepot насколько я понимаю, `DataRowView` немного не то, ибо я ловлю строку из таблицы и получается вывести только 1 строку в плитку, но при выполнении `Binding`, `ItemsControl` выдает мне всю таблицу, не знаю как эта магия работает

Comment: Для отображения одной строки таблицы, я полагаю, не ItemsControl нужен. А какие-то отдельные контролы, привязанные к ячейкам. Я бы на вашем месте вязался не напрямую к DataTable, а создал бы вьюмодель, коллекцию этих вьюмоделей и в C# коде тупо скопировал бы туда данные из DataTable. Но лучше, всё-таки использовать ORM. Вы запутались, распутывайтесь.

Comment: @aepot я думал над этим, только вот не смог правильно захухлить, не могли бы вы накидать ссылочек на реализацию колекций)